# Is 'a fast one' necessarily fast?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Try to gain an unfair advantage.

That's what Lexico says. But I can't stop thinking that that 'fast' in the expression 'pull a fast one' may actually denote only something swift, not drawn-out in time. Is it so?

Comment: Your question isn’t entirely clear. You seem to contradict yourself. You at first (In the title) seem to say “a fast one” doesn’t need to be fast. But then you say it denotes “only something swift” (ie: must be fast).  Which do you think is true?

Comment: @OrbitalAussie I'm not saying anything, I'm asking! The title has a question mark at the end!